# power failure handling in Apache Nutch 2.x

Tags: apache, hadoop, web-crawler, nutch

I have setup a cluster to crawl few websites from WWW. I am using Apache Nutch 2.3.1 with Hadoop and Hbase. I have cluster backup also. But when power failure goes long then even this backup is finished and complete cluster goes down in no time. When power problem is solved (somehow), I want to resume my job from where it was at last time. For example, if my crawler was crawling 1000 URLs and after 50%, cluster goes down. I want that Nutch should fetch only remaining 50% and should not fetched those documents that are already fetched.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Yes brother. There is built in option for resume at fetch time. You have to just update crawl script

Comment: Yes brother. There is built in option for resume at fetch time. You have to just update crawl script

Comment: can you please share the fix how to do?

Comment: You have to just enable -resume flag in crawl script and it will start working

Comment: this is the script : https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/nutch/branches/2.x/src/bin/crawl
where should i update. I am newbee. pls don't mind

Comment: How should I share file with you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165624/discussion-between-rajeev-and-shafiq).